# Is it possible to run a teams bot without password or do I have a problem when creating it?

Tags: python, authentication, botframework

I created a teams bot with the python framework, tested it using the bot emulator locally, then moved it to my server and the using the new endpoint I can discuss with my bot properly from the emulator.

However the `config.py` file (copied from different sample from Microsoft as [this one on github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot)), [the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams) (citing: *Your registration needs the messaging endpoint from your deployed web service and your web service needs the ID and password created from your registration.*) and other online website or issue I visited ask for a password.

When I registered my bot, I didn't have any password (see the screenshot of my old bot, now deleted, the ID is not a problem). I didn't got any pop-up with my password as some tutorial mention. I don't have any passwords neither on the App registration panel on Microsoft Azure.

[image]

So I tried to run the bot without, but while I'm able to read the message from Teams or the Web chat, I get unauthorized errors when trying to answer, and the bot emulator give me an error 401 `"The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect` when trying to enter only the APP ID.

Is the error I am getting when trying to answer the Web Chat or the Teams chat (`[on_turn_error] unhandled error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'`) caused by my lack of Password, and then how can I get one, or is it a abnormal and a problem in my code?

Comment: Is that screenshot from the Bot Framework portal? What happens when you click "Manage Microsoft App ID and password"? Do you have an Azure subscription?

Comment: @KyleDelaney it is. During the creation of the bot, clicking open a portal.azure.com tab, where I can register an application which gives me an APP ID, which I have to paste in the field below the button to create the bot. Once the bot created, I can click on it again from the settings tab in the Bot Framework portal  and it now open the linked application in the azure portal

Comment: @KyleDelaney I don't have an Azure subscription. From what I read I thought I didn't need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot Framework bots use Azure Active Directory to manage their identities and authenticate themselves. Your bot will need an app ID and password to send messages to any channel except for Bot Framework Emulator.

Whether you have an active Azure subscription or not, you will still need to use the Azure portal to manage your AAD app registration, which is how you get your password. The password is a client secret that's been added to the app registration, and you can generate one by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings#get-registration-password).

Comment: Ok mvm my previous comment. I actually skipped to step 5 and somehow found the client secret option. However the rest of the instructions doesn't match to anything and the UI seems to have been updated

Comment: is there a waiting time before the password works. Because I get an `[on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'` and when trying to fill the APP ID + Password in the Bot Emulator, I still get the `POST 400 error: "The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect`

Comment: The Emulator doesn't care about AAD. The Emulator just checks that the app ID and password that you entered into the Emulator are the same as the app ID and password you entered into the bot. Have you entered the same app ID and password into config.py?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where you're getting your app ID and password from? Is it possible that you've made the same mistake as [this other developer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2998) by using the ID from the client secret rather than the actual AAD app ID?

Comment: I used the same password/login. I even tried in the past with password like toto/tata and I had the same error from the botemulator. I cloned the sample bot builder sample repo, made a new env with only the requirements.txt package and used toto/toto login/password for the 02-echo bot, and I still have the same Bot Emulator error as above (Post 400)

Comment: I'm using the APP ID from the line pointed by the red arrow in the screenshot above, which is the same Aplication ID  as in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7izz.png (red field) (it's the overwiew selection, in the right menu)

Comment: For the password, I get it from this field (red value again)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSO3f.png

Comment: It seems I was wrong when I said Emulator doesn't care about AAD. While Emulator does allow for blank credentials, if you provide credentials then they'll need to be valid. The screenshots you've provided make it look like you are gathering your credentials correctly, so it's unclear what's wrong with them. You can try reading through the documentation to make sure you're doing everything right, and you can try creating a new AAD app just in case that works. What are the supported account types found in the app registration's Authentication blade?

Comment: Somethins strange, I created my bot by joining the URL https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new directly from the documentation. I wanted to create a new bot + new app to check as you said, and when I go to https://dev.botframework.com/bots/ it give me a "create a bot" button, which lead me to the azure portal, where I select "bots channel registration". And when I try to create the bot, it tells me it can't cause I don't have a subscription (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN7mE.png). I never saw it cause when I created the bot from the direct link I didn't have any subscription problem. is it normal?

Comment: I created a new bot / new AAD but it still doesn't work (same error, `access token`)/ they are not accepted by the bot emulator too. I suppose blade mean selection (regarding the right menu). The supported account is set to "Accounts in this organizational directory only ([MY] University only - Single tenant)"

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-create#bots-and-microsoft-azure) should answer your questions about using the deprecated Bot Framework portal despite the push to migrate everyone to the Azure portal. It sounds like the supported account types is the problem after all. You want to create an app registration that's available in all organizations by referring to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration#manual-app-registration). Is my answer acceptable now?

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help, It indeed solves my problem, thus I will accept the answer. I am not sure to totally understand why I can't use one organization account. I mean, I understand that the doc say "you must use a multi-tenants types" so I have to, but I intend to only use my bot in teams in my organization. Is it for security reason? Anyway, thanks again

Comment: That AAD app registration isn't for you, it's for the bot. The Bot Framework isn't in your organization. I'm glad I could help